# Discrete Probability Question With No Named Distribution

Tags: probability

I've got a real world probability problem that I have been able to solve easily using simulation but that I am struggling to find (out of pure interest) an analytic solution to. For privacy reasons, I have changed both the context and the actual numbers.

A vendor is selling tickets. Customers either purchase 1 ticket with probability 60%, 2 tickets with probability 30%, or 3 tickets with probability 10%. If the vendor needs to sell 10 tickets, how many customers on average does he need to sell to (assuming customer purchases are iid)?

A simulation produces an average of 6.6 customers, but I am curious what an analytic solution to this might look like (if there exists a convenient one) as there is no named distribution I can think of that corresponds to this problem.

Comment: I would go by backwards induction.  If the vendor has sold $9$ tickets, then only $1$ more customer is needed.  If the vendor has sold $8$ then you expect it to take $2$ customers with probability $.6$ and $1$ customer with probability $.4$ and so on.

Comment: Should say:  when I ran this computation I got $6.9\overline 3$ which is significantly greater than your $6.6$ though perhaps I did it too hastily.

Comment: I would be interested in comparing our code to see what we are doing differently but I'm not sure if it's generally approved to post code in comments?

Comment: @lulu Not exactly $6.9\overline 3$ but exactly $6.933335296$

Comment: @Henry. Yes, you are right.

Comment: @lulu, back at my desk, I checked my simulation and realized that I was undercounting the number of customers by one when the ticket count was reached at either 11 or 12 (not strictly 10), which explains the difference between our answers and why yours is correct.

Comment: @SimonSaltine  Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write out the recursive solution sketched in the comments:  Let $E_n$ denote the expected number of customers needed to sell $n$ tickets.  Then, of course, $E_0=0, E_1=1$  We compute $E_2=.6\times 2+.4\times 1 =1.6$.

Recursively, we see that, for $n≥3$,  $$E_n=1+.6E_{n-1}+.3E_{n-2}+.1E_{n-2}$$

Since the associated cubic does not have pleasant roots, the [closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a%5B0%5D%3D0%2C+a%5B1%5D%3D1%2C+a%5B2%5D%3D1.6%2C+a%5Bn%5D%3D1%2B.6*a%5Bn-1%5D%2B.3*a%5Bn-2%5D%2B+.1*a%5Bn-3%5D) for the solution is not pleasant.  It is, however, easy to compute $E_n$ for small $n$ and one gets $$\boxed {E_{10}=6.933335296}$$  matching the result obtained by @Henry.

Answer (score 5):

One analytical approach is find the probability that you have *not* sold $10$ tickets after seeing $n$ customers. This is the sum of the coefficients of $x^k$ with $0\le k \le 9$ in the expansion of $$\left(0.6x+0.3x^2+0.1x^3\right)^n$$

For example with $n=2$ you get $0.36x^2+0.36x^3+0.21x^4+0.06x^5+0.01x^6$ and adding up the coefficients with $0\le k \le 9$ gives $1$ as you might have thought anyway; it becomes interesting when $4 \le n\le 9$ as then you may or may not have sold $10$ tickets. For various values of $n$ this gives

```
n customers      0 1 2 3  4      5       6       7          8           9           10+
P(tickets < 10)  1 1 1 1  0.9909 0.90126 0.64152 0.3055968  0.0839808   0.010077696  0
```

and if you add these probabilities up then you get the expected number of customers when you have sold at least $10$ tickets of $6.933335296$, as lulu found

Comment: I assume you mean $0.1x^3$ instead of $0.1x^4$?

Comment: Also, could you provide some intuition as to why you would start at n=0? My intuition would be to start at n=1, but then I'd be off by 1.

Comment: @SimonSaltine I did mean $0.1x^3$ - thank you -edited

Comment: @SimonSaltine. The expectation of a non-negative integer random variable is $E[X]=P(X>0)+P(X>1)+P(X>2)+\cdots$.  It is also $E[X]=P(X\ge 1)+P(X\ge 2)+P(X\ge 3)+\cdots$ but the first of these two expressions is easier to calculate here

Comment: I understand how you calculate the probabilities above, and I'm familiar with this property of the expectations of non-negative integers, but I am having conceptual difficulties seeing how you tie these two together here. It seems to me like you've calculated P(tickets<10|N=n) where N is the number of customers. If that's the case, then I'm not sure I see how we are using the above property of expectation. If this is not the case, then I guess I'm not clear what exactly the random variable X is when you employ the above property of expectation.

Comment: I am saying for example, that if the probability you have sold fewer then ten tickets after $n=7$ customers is $0.3055968$ then the probability the number of customers you need to sell ten tickets exceeds $7$ is also $0.3055968$.  So yes: $P(X>n)=P(T <10 \mid N=n)$ where $X$ is the number of customers needed to have sold ten tickets; if you have not sold ten tickets by the $n$th customer then you need more than $n$ customers to have sold ten tickets

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; this was very helpful!